# Ionic: Subheader is not displayed in tabs-based app in Android

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am struggling to add subheader into tabs based Ionic application. The problem is that the subheader is not shown in Android, but it is shown in iOS.

[image]

I want to use subheader for a search bar, so that it is not scrolled away with content bellow it.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create a test app based on tabs project:

`ionic start subheader-test tabs`

2. Modify `.\subheader-test\www\templates\tab-dash.html` to add subheader on Status tab so that it looks like the file bellow:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader bar-balanced">
    <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h2>Welcome to Ionic</h2>
    <p>
      ....
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

3. Start Ionic lab:

`ionic serve -l`

I tested `ion-content` with combinations of `has-subheader` and `has-header` classed but it was to no avail.

Subheader is not show in Android version of the app in any browser I tested (Chrome, Firefox, IE 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may solve the problem:

www/css/**style.css**

```
.platform-android .bar-subheader.has-tabs-top{
  top:93px !important;
}

.platform-android .has-subheader.has-tabs-top{
  top:137px;
}
```

Or maybe you can add `$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');` in **app.js**  like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
     //
    }
```

Comment: I used the option with css styling - it works. Thank you very much I did not think I get a correct answer so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't quite work for me.  I had to delete the `"has-tabs-top"` class from the subheader CSS to get it to work (looking in the Chrome console, that class was not assigned to the subheader when running ionic serve --lab)