# Ionic: Header overlaps content when subheader is hidden in tabs-based app in iOS

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I have a nav button to show/hide subheader in tabs-based app. Problem is that when the subheader is hidden, header overlaps the content (`ion-content`) in iOS. Title **Welcome to Ionic** is hidden bellow the header.

[image: Welcome to Ionic is hidden bellow header in iOS when subheader is hidden.]

Subheader is hidden and title **Welcome to Ionic** should be visible in iOS.

[image: When subheader is shown, content is displayed correctly.]

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Create a test app based on tabs project:

`ionic start subheader-test tabs`

2. Modify `.\subheader-test\www\templates\tab-dash.html` to add subheader and show/hide button:

```html
    <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
    
      <ion-nav-buttons  side="right">
        <!-- SEARCH ICON in header bar -->
        <button class="icon ion-search button button-clear"
            ng-click="toggleSubheader();">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader bar-balanced" ng-show="showSubheader">
        <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
    
      <ion-content class="padding" ng-class="{'has-subheader' : showSubheader}">
        <h2>Welcome to Ionic</h2>
        <p>
        This is the Ionic starter for tabs-based apps. For other starters and ready-made templates, check out the <a href="http://market.ionic.io/starters" target="_blank">Ionic Market</a>.
        </p>
        <p>
          To edit the content of each tab, edit the corresponding template file in <code>www/templates/</code>. This template is <code>www/templates/tab-dash.html</code>
        </p>
        <p>
    ......
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

3. Add `toggleSubheader()` function into `DashCtrl` controller in `.\subheader-test\www\js\controllers.js`:

   ```
   .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.showSubheader = true;

     $scope.toggleSubheader = function() {
       $scope.showSubheader = !$scope.showSubheader;
     };
   })
   ```
4. Modify `.\subheader-test\www\ css\style.css` to fix [Subheader is not displayed in tabs-based app in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815839/ionic-subheader-is-not-displayed-in-tabs-based-app-in-android/37816671#37816671):

   ```
   .platform-android .bar-subheader.has-tabs-top{
     top:93px !important;
   }

   .platform-android .has-subheader.has-tabs-top{
     top:137px;
   }
   ```
5. Start Ionic lab:

`ionic serve -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by css class applicable for iOS only when subheader is hidden.

css:

```
/* Shift content down when subheader is shown in iOS. */
.platform-ios .has-hidden-subheader{
  top:44px;
}
```

html:

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-class="{
   'has-subheader' : showSubheader ,
   'has-hidden-subheader' : !showSubheader}">
```